# How do I store version number strings in a django database so they are correctly comparable/sortable

Tags: python, mysql, django, tuples

I'm developing/maintaining/curating a database of test results gathered from various wearable research devices. Each device has three main components, each of which has two version numbers (firmware and hardware). I'm using a django app to provide a web interface to the database. The version numbers represented either as straight integers, or as triplets (Major, minor, build). The integers are easy enough to handle, and I can obviously store the triplets as strings, but as strings they won't sort correctly or compare correctly, for example if I want only test results produced by devices with firmware version less than 14.x.y.

I can't use a float because of the second 'decimal point' separator. I thought of maybe going for a hack by storing it as a date, but that will limit minor numbers to less than 12 and build numbers to less than 29, and besides I **know** this is a terrible solution. I probably shouldn't even confess to having thought of it.

Short of extending the database with some PL/SQL to provide a comparison function that treats the strings correctly, is there a simple way to do this? If not, can I even use my custom SQL function with django?

Comment: Why you do not store it as a String?

Comment: Because '10' sorts before '2' as a string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Store them as a zero-padded strings:

```
>>> def sortable_version(version):
...     return '.'.join(bit.zfill(5) for bit in version.split('.'))
... 
>>> sortable_version('1.1')
'00001.00001'
>>> sortable_version('2')
'00002'
>>> sortable_version('2.1.10')
'00002.00001.00010'
>>> sortable_version('10.1')
'00010.00001'
>>> sortable_version('2') > sortable_version('1.3.4')
True
>>> sortable_version('10') > sortable_version('2')
True
>>> sortable_version('2.3.4') > sortable_version('2')
True
```

And you can always show regular version from this zero-padded format:

```
>>> def normalize_version(padded_version):
...     return '.'.join(bit.lstrip('0') for bit in padded_version.split('.'))
... 
>>> normalize_version('00010')
'10'
>>> normalize_version('00002.00001.00010')
'2.1.10'
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this. It's not exactly efficient, but this is what I've seen several frameworks / libraries do that had to deal with this issue, and the advantage is that SQL ordering / comparison "just works".

Comment: Right, I thought about doing this, but wasn't sure how to determine how much to pad, since it would involve knowing the maximal length of the individual version components of all the other version numbers in the databases. Then again, if we even have more than five digits for a single component, we're doing something wrong I guess.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called "natural sort".

Another way to implement this is to use database sorting. Here is an example for Postgres:

```
class VersionRecordManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().extra(
            select={
                'natural_version':
                    "string_to_array(                     "  
                    "   regexp_replace(                   "  # Remove everything except digits
                    "       version, '[^\d\.]+', '', 'g'  "  # and dots, then split string into
                    "   ), '.'                            "  # an array of integers.
                    ")::int[]                             "
            }
        )

    def available_versions(self):
        return self.filter(available=True).order_by('-natural_version')

    def last_stable(self):
        return self.available_versions().filter(stable=True).first()

class VersionRecord(models.Model):
    objects = VersionRecordManager()
    version = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    stable = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```