# django filter comparison by version string

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model like the following:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField()
```

with the following objects:

```
obj1: version = '9.0.1'
obj2: version = '9.2'
obj3: version = '9.2.3'
obj4: version = '10.0'
obj5: version = 'UNKNOWN'
```

I want to do the following filter

```
MyModel.objects.filter(version__gte='9.2.3')
```

That will return obj3 and obj4.
What is the best way to approach this? 
Im using Django 1.8

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208438/how-do-i-store-version-number-strings-in-a-django-database-so-they-are-correctly

Comment: @Bijoy - Will this work even if i have non numeric values in some objects?

Comment: I think you should change version `'UNKNOWN'` to `'0'`, in your db, you can use django shell to achieve it.